# Funcion sin cuerpo en preprocesado de C

Tags: c, preprocesador

Me gustaría saber el funcionamiento o el comportamiento que tendría esta función :

`#define SHA3_ASSERT( x )`

Encontrada en: https://github.com/brainhub/SHA3IUF/blob/master/sha3.c

No tiene cuerpo, y no entiendo el uso que se le da. Tampoco encuentro en ningún documento sobre el preprocesador de C donde se hable de funciones sin definir. Solo he visto que a veces se usa la macro:
`#define UNUSED (x)` para evitar warnings en variables no utilizadas.
Al igual que la función SHA3_ASSERT, hay otras como :

```
#define SHA3_TRACE( format, ...)
#define SHA3_TRACE_BUF( format, buf, l, ...)
```

Que tampoco tienen cuerpo, alguien podria ayudarme a entenderlas? Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que hacen esas *macros* (que no funciones) es muy sencillo: **absolutamente nada**. Literalmente: al ser *macros*, el preprocesador las procesa antes de la fase de compilado. Se sustituyen, **literalmente**, por su valor ... que es **nada**, por lo que el compilador **ni siquiera llega a verlas**.

Es raro encontrar una macro así, de forma aislada. Normalmente, se usan en combinación con otras macros, en *condicionales* para alterar el comportamiento del código según ciertas condiciones, especificadas en tiempo de compilación.

Un ejemplo suele ser la macro `assert( )`, presente en la librería del lenguaje, que sirve para abortar el programa si alguna condición **no** se cumple. Suele definirse así:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert( X )
#else
#define assert( X ) real_call_to_assert( X, ... otros argumentos ... )
#endif
```

Podemos leer lo anterior como:

> Si la macro `NDEBUG` **está** definida
>   Define la macro `assert( X )` como `nada`
>   **En otro caso**
>   Define la macro `assert( X )` como una llamada a la función `real_call_to_assert( )`, pasándole el argumento `X`

Ahora, al compilar nuestro código, podemos alterar su comportamiento, en base a si definimos o no la macro `NDEBUG`:

- Versión para depuración: `gcc -g -ggdb ...`
- Versión para distribución: `gcc -DNDEBUG -O2 ...`

Comment: Muchas gracias @Juanjo, como dices , esas macros no se usan de forma aislada, y se define un comportamiento o no dependiendo de condiciones. En el código del enlace, no veo que nunca se lleguen a definir, pero si que las usa en el código y no hacen nada. Se puede suponer que esta incompleto o para definirlo en un futuro?. Suponía que no hacían nada ya que hice un código de prueba. Pero entonces que intención tendría el autor para llegar a usarlas en el código?? Sabrías decírmelo? Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Puedo suponer ... como dices, pueden ser para futuras ampliaciones, o una forma rápida de eliminar llamadas que ya no son necesarias. Y añadiría que es una forma de programar poco clara y que lleva a confusiones :-)